# License of Flowground SFTP Component

Tags: flowground

To the Flowground developers: The license of the Flowground SFTP component is specified inconsistently. In the connectors catalog "Apache 2.0" is specified as license (https://flowground.net/de/loesungen/konnektoren-katalog/sftp). But in the `package.json` "BSD-2-Clause" is stated (https://github.com/flowground/sftp-component/blob/master/package.json). I assume that the specification in the `package.json` is right. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was a mistake in the Connector-Catalog. Has been fixed to "BSD-2-Clause".